# Open avi file in particular div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have dropdown animated menu from where I can select particular video file which I want to play it on same page in particular section. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `<video>` tag in HTML. Here is the [detailed description](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_videos.asp) with examples. Give a try yourself.

You can load the video like,

```
jQuery('.dropdown').change(function(event) {
    jQuery("#div-id").empty().append("***Video here*****");
});
```

One more [reference here](http://www.ehow.com/how_6825163_embed-avi-video-html.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that most AVI files will not be playable in a `<video>` tag.